# How to mock behavior of AutoMapper Mapping in Nsubstitute

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nsubstitute, automapper-3

Currently I have something like this :-

```
    var someclass1 = JsonConvert.Deserialize<SomeClass1>(RandomData);
    var someclass2 = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Models.SomeClass2.SomeClass2>(someclass1);

    Assert.Equal(someclass2.Count, 1);
```

I know in order to do this I need to create a mock for IMappingEngine, but how do I mock the mapping above ?

Comment: Why mock at all? You can simply use AM in your test.

Comment: its not working that way, I have tried out multiple solutions, my mappings are disposed off randomly and get wierd test results. That is why I wanted to mock it. Do u have any idea how we can do it in nsubstitute ? Ofcourse I know I can simply use AM.

Comment: `its not working that way, I have tried out multiple solutions, my mappings are disposed off randomly and get wierd test results.` Can you show us that code, and the weird results of which you speak?

Comment: its corporate code cant show, but what happens is that whenever I try to map using Mapper.Map, it throws a mapping exception even if I load the profiles correctly. Sometimes the very same tests pass too. So that is why I asked whether I could mock the mapping instead of depending on Mapper.Map.

Comment: @SharthakGhosh , you are using Automapper in service locator pattern using the previous structure. AutoMapper also has the `IMapper` that can be injected into dependent classes and mocked if needed. Check their documentation

Comment: If AM works in your app, you should use it the same way in your tests.

Comment: If the mapper is a dependency for the class you are testing, mock it like `IMapper mapper = Substitute.For<IMapper>()`. If you are trying to do a maping test, build your `MapperConfiguration`, add the profile to it, act against it.